# Use a submit <button> instead of <input> button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

i want to submit a form with `<button>` instead of `<input>`.
I know a `<button>` cant handle the form like a submit `<input>` and i have to use the onclick method.

I tried several things but it doesn't work

```
<button name="<?php echo $name; ?>" onclick="document.<?php echo $this->action; ?>.submit()"> ... ( Action URL of the form )
<button name="<?php echo $name; ?>" onclick="document.iso<?php echo rand(); ?>.submit()">... ( name of the form )
<button name="<?php echo $name; ?>" onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo $this->action; ?>'">... ( Action url of the form )
```

Does someone know an answer ?

Comment: what is the generated name of your form?

Comment: You want to submit the form on Click event?

Comment: *"I know a <button> cant handle the form like a submit `<input>`"* - you know wrong. Buttons submit forms.

Comment: [-This-](http://rickyrosario.com/blog/using-the-html-button-element-in-place-of-input-type-submit/) may be useful

Comment: buttons inside a form can submit form without any onclick event

Comment: The name of the form is placed in the php variable $name

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the `type="submit"` like property of [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

```
<button type="submit" name="<?php echo $name; ?>">Submit</button>
```

Comment: `submit` is the default type for a button element, you can omit the attribute entirely.